# Grails : get a list of elements with a belongsTo relationship?

Tags: grails

Assuming I have a `Person` and a `Status`. If `Status` is like this :

```
class Status {
    String text
    Person author
}
```

I would have done something like this to get the messages list of the current user :

```
def messages = Status.withCriteria {
    author { 
        eq 'username', currentPerson.username
    }
}
```

But if my relationship in `Status` is like this, how can I do so?

```
static belongsTo = [Person]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to use the map notation for belongsTo, so I would do it like this:

```
class Status {
   String text
   static belongsTo = [author: Person]
}
```

Then you're query is easy:

```
def messages = Status.findAllByAuthor(currentPerson)
```

If you had bidirectional added into Person with hasMany:

```
class Person {

   static hasMany = [messages: Status]
}
```

You could also do this:

```
def messages = currentPerson.messages
```